# How to render partial templates for an array of objects within a helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, templates, rendering

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.13 and I would like to render partial templates for an array of objects within a helper method. That is, in my helper file I have:

```
def render_articles(articles)
  articles.each do |article|
    render :partial => ...
  end
end
```

The above method, however, doesn't return partial templates but an array. How can I properly render those?

Comment: why not just `render :partial => '...', :collection => articles`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `each` block you have doesn't return the contents of the block but rather returns the array itself. You need a mechanism to return the contents.

A method:

```
def render_articles(articles)
  html = ""
  articles.each do |article|
    html += render :partial => ...
  end
  html.html_safe
end
```

Another method:

```
def render_articles(articles)
  articles.inject("") { |html, article| html + render :partical =>... }.html_safe
end
```

Comment: By using your code I get the plain text of partial templates and that text is not rendered as HTML code, unless I use `html_safe` method. But, generally speaking, is it dangerous to use the `html_safe` method?

Comment: @user502052 You have to use `html_safe`. It's not dangerous in this context.

Comment: You can also do, shorter : `articles.map { |article| render partial: ... }.join('').html_safe`

Comment: @Olivier El Mekki - Out of curiosity, what is the most performant method between the two proposed solutions (`inject` and `map`)?

Comment: @user502052 I would think that, under the hood, the operations are very similar. I couldn't imagine the performance being noticeable from a user perspective.

Comment: `#map` is slightly more efficient, but only with high computation : https://gist.github.com/oelmekki/6f5fcc120e052a84ffdd . This should not make any difference in your case (unless you generate 10 000 partials, and then that would not be your worse problem :) )